# How to politely ask for a pre-defence review (areas of concern/topics that need to be covered)?

Tags: phd, defense

Could you please give some suggestions for asking pre-defence review from an opponent. In my case, I have to do it by myself by writing an e-mail. What words would be appropriate and what should be exactly asked (quite likely I shouldn't ask for the whole very detailed review).

**For example, how to end this?**

> Good to hear that the thesis arrived. Once you have read the thesis,
> identified areas of concern and topics that need to be addressed,
> could you please ...

Comment: Is this generally done in your university? Because around here (in Gothenburg, Sweden) we invite external opponents precisely so that students don't already know in advance what questions they are going to get ;) asking for feedback in advance would feel a little unbecoming here, like asking the teacher what's going to be on the exam.

Comment: @xLeitix In Germany and the Netherlands, asking for feedback seems very common in the pre-submission stage - the point being that the thesis could still be improved at this point, which seems to be in everyone's best interest. Asking for feedback post-submission, but pre-defense seems less common, though, probably for the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reword the second sentence as

> Please let me know if there are corrections/improvements to be made.

This is some straightforward, down-to-business tone which feels perfectly fine with collaborators even if you've just agreed to work together (and in a sense, the opponent has agreed to help you work on your thesis!). The original wording has two disagreeable properties: first, it is quite wordy with you beating around the bush in a communication that doesn't need to be this formal (IMHO) and second, you kind of guide the reader through these tasks one by one, *as if assigning a job to them*. Instead, your intention is to make a request, so "Do X, Y and Z and then *please*, do N". Maybe it is just me but that rubbed me the wrong way.